# Find all $f$ such that $f\left(m^{2}+n^{2}\right)=f(m)^{2}+f(n)^{2},$

Tags: functions, induction, contest-math, functional-equations, alternative-proof

**Question** -

Find all $f: \mathbb{N}_{0} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{0}$ which satisfy

(a) $f\left(m^{2}+n^{2}\right)=f(m)^{2}+f(n)^{2},$ for all $m, n$ in $\mathbb{N}_{0}$

(b) $f(1)>0$

**my try** -

I showed that $f(n)=n$ for all $n<10$ by using given conditions very easily ...
but i am not able to apply induction to prove that $f(n)=n$ for all n because there is square term inside...i think this question has different strategy to solve..

any help will be appreciated
thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**  Induction works.  Use the identities
$$(2k+1)^2+(k-2)^2=(k+2)^2+(2k-1)^2$$
and
$$(2k+2)^2+(k-4)^2=(k+4)^2+(2k-2)^2\,.$$

---

By the OP's claim, $f(n)=n$ for $n<10$.  Suppose now that $n\geq 10$ is such that $f(m)=m$ for all integers $m$ such that $0\leq m <n$.

If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k\geq 4$.  Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\big(f(2k+1)\big)^2+\big(f(k-2)\big)^2&=f\big((2k+1)^2+(k-2)^2\big)\\&=f\big((k+2)^2+(2k-1)^2\big)\\&=\big(f(k+2)\big)^2+\big(f(2k-1)\big)^2\,.\end{align}$$
By induction hypothesis, $f(k-2)=k-2$, $f(k+2)=k+2$, and $f(2k-1)=2k-1$.  This gives $f(n)=f(2k+1)=2k+1=n$.

If $n$ is even, then $n=2k+2$ for some integer $k\geq 4$.  Apply the same strategy as the previous paragraph to show that $f(n)=n$.

---

Anyway, we can easily check that $f(n)=n$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots,9$.  Plugging $m:=0$ and $n:=0$ into the functional equation shows that $2\,\big(f(0)\big)^2=f(0)$, so $\big(2\,f(0)-1\big)\,f(0)=0$.  Since $f(0)$ is an integer, $2\,f(0)-1$ is odd, whence unequal to $0$.  This means $f(0)=0$.

Plugging in $m:=1$ and $n:=0$ into the functional equation yields $f(1)\,\big(f(1)-1\big)=0$.  As $f(1)>0$, we conclude $f(1)=1$.  Hence, $$f(2)=f(1^2+1^2)=\big(f(1)\big)^2+\big(f(1)\big)^2=1^2+1^2=2\,.$$

This shows that 
$$f(4)=f(0^2+2^2)=\big(f(0)\big)^2+\big(f(2)\big)^2=0^2+2^2=4\,,$$
$$f(5)=f(1^2+2^2)=\big(f(1)\big)^2+\big(f(2)\big)^2=1^2+2^2=5\,,$$
and
$$f(8)=f(2^2+2^2)=\big(f(2)\big)^2+\big(f(2)\big)^2=2^2+2^2=8\,.$$
Thus, 
$$\begin{align}
25&=0^2+5^2=\big(f(0)\big)^2+\big(f(5)\big)^2=f(0^2+5^2)\\
&=f(25)=f(3^2+4^2)=\big(f(3)\big)^2+\big(f(4)\big)^2\\
&=\big(f(3)\big)^2+4^2=\big(f(3)\big)^2+16\,.
\end{align}$$
As $f(3)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, we obtain $f(3)=3$.  Consequently,
$$f(9)=f(0^2+3^2)=\big(f(0)\big)^2+\big(f(3)\big)^2=0^2+3^2=9\,,$$

Now,
$$\begin{align}
50&=5^2+5^2=\big(f(5)\big)^2+\big(f(5)\big)^2=f(5^2+5^2)\\
&=f(50)=f(1^2+7^2)=\big(f(1)\big)^2+\big(f(7)\big)^2\\
&=1^2+\big(f(7)\big)^2=1+\big(f(7)\big)^2\,.
\end{align}$$
Thus, $f(7)=7$.  Finally, from
$$\begin{align}
85&=2^2+9^2=\big(f(2)\big)^2+\big(f(9)\big)^2=f(2^2+9^2)\\
&=f(85)=f(6^2+7^2)=\big(f(6)\big)^2+\big(f(7)\big)^2\\
&=\big(f(6)\big)^2+7^2=\big(f(6)\big)^2+49\,,
\end{align}$$
we obtain $f(6)=6$.

---

Let $S$ be the subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ consisting of all nonnegative integers that can be written as a sum of two perfect squares of integers.  For a description of $S$, see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).  The solutions $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb{C}$ to the functional equation
$$f(m^2+n^2)=\big(f(m)\big)^2+\big(f(n)\big)^2$$
for all $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ are

- $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$,
- $f(n)=\dfrac12\,g(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ where $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to \{-1,+1\}$ is such that $g(s)=1$ for all $s\in S$, and
- $f(n)=n\,g(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ where $g:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\to \{-1,+1\}$ is such that $g(s)=1$ for all $s\in S$.

Comment: but is it necessary to find values upto 10 ??? can we just find for 2 or 3 then induct using above methods.....

Comment: If you want to use the identities I wrote, then for $n=2k+1$, you have $(k-2)^2$ in the respective identity.  Therefore, you need that $k\geq 2$, making $n=2k+1\geq 5$.  For $n=2k+2$, you have $(k-4)^2$ in the respective identity, and so you need $k\geq 4$, making $n=2k+2\geq 10$.  That means the inductive step can only performed for $n\geq \max\{5,10\}=10$; thus, you need to know $f(0)$, $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $\ldots$, $f(9)$.  That is, the threshold for my identities is $n=10$.  However, you may find a different set of identities that works with a lower threshold value of $n$.